# Implement a typeface based on a 3x3 bitmap matrix

Tags: code-golf, printable-ascii

### Input

A single-character string containing an uppercase or a lowercase letter from the English alphabet.

Alternatively, you may handle only uppercase or only lowercase letters as input.

### Output

[image]

This 3x3 typeface of the input letter ([source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:3x3_typeface.svg)), with two distinct, printable ASCII characters of your choice (excluding tabs and newlines) to represent the black and white pixels. They also must be consistent: if a character is used to represent a black pixel for an input, that same character can't be used to represent a white pixel for another input.

You may alternatively create a string or list of characters of length 11 (12 if a trailing newline is present) and output that.

In this demonstration, the selected characters will be `.` for black and   for white:

```
A
 . 
...
. .

B
.. 
...
...

C
...
.  
...

D
.. 
. .
.. 

E
...
.. 
...

F
...
.. 
.  

G
.. 
. .
...

H
. .
...
. .

I
...
 . 
...

J
  .
. .
...

K
. .
.. 
. .

L
.  
.  
...

M
...
...
. .

N
...
. .
. .

O
...
. .
...

P
...
...
.  

Q
...
...
  .

R
...
.  
.  

S
 ..
 . 
.. 

T
...
 . 
 . 

U
. .
. .
...

V
. .
. .
 . 

W
. .
...
...

X
. .
 . 
. .

Y
. .
 . 
 . 

Z
.. 
 . 
 ..
```

While a trailing newline is optional, the intermediate newline is required.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so try to create your solution with fewest bytes possible. It also uses the [standard I/O](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/91472) defined by the community.

---

Very thanks to [@emanresuA](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/497390/emanresu-a) for helping me on The Nineteenth Byte.

[Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/26213/91472)

Comment: To give credit, this font was created by [Anders de Flon](http://luc.devroye.org/fonts-51468.html)

Comment: Output example shows digits 0..9 as well. But everything else just refers to alpha.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact You can ignore the digits, since the input is clearly defined as only letters.

Comment: But better would be to have an output image that has no extraneous information.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 42 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ḢOị“©Ịı)ḍ6*,ÐÄÄ<Ụ,+ɼɲ4øeọṅịḲ{§*/ṡƑ’Bs9¤s3Y
```

A full program that accepts a single character string in upper case and prints the typeface for that character using `1`s, `0`s and newlines.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AVgAp/9qZWxsef//4biiT@G7i@KAnMKp4buKxLEp4biNNiosw5DDhMOEPOG7pCwrybzJsjTDuGXhu43huYXhu4vhuLJ7wqcqL@G5ocaR4oCZQnM5wqRzM1n///9K)**

#### How?

I don't think there is any pattern to exploit here so this is just a simple compression. (Trying to cater for `A`, `J`, and `S` being the only characters with no ink in the top left pixel is more expensive for example).

```
ḢOị“...’Bs9¤s3Y - Main Link: list of characters  e.g. "A"
Ḣ               - head                                'A'
 O              - ordinal -> Ord                      65 (N.B. 65 % 26 = 13)
           ¤    - nilad followed by links as a nilad
   “...’        -   a big number
        B       -   convert to binary
                         -> flat list of pixel values of O, P, Q, ..., Z, A, B, ..., N
                                               (indices: 1  2  3      12 13 14  ... 26(0))
         s9     -   split into chunks of length nine -> 26 binary lists
  ị             - {Ord} index into {that}             [0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1]
                    (1-indexed and modular)
            s3  - split into chunks of length three   [[0,1,0],[1,1,1],[1,0,1]]
              Y - join with newline characters        [0,1,0,'\n',1,1,1,'\n',1,0,1]
                - implicit, smashing print
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 119 bytes

Expects the ASCII code of an upper case letter. Returns a string of 0's (white) and 1's (black).

```javascript
c=>`876
543
210`.replace(/./g,n=>parseInt("DDEED5CAAA99B5CDBDDBAD3A8E"[c%=26]+"PR41GYY72NHE79FJYZWZL33D75"[c],36)>>n&1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY5Ba4MwAEbv/oogbCTY2WoarXQRonHtShljPRQ7Cg1ZdB0ukSi7jP12l/PY6Xs83uH7EF9ikPbaj3favKmpoZOk@WWVJh5ZYi@OFpfQqr4TUsF5OG9nmua9sIN61CP0Oa8qTkrGWJYVpOQF5wXjmK0q/1Xe0Dg5B/7zyzLa1HUaP22rNHvY1afjaY8xT4lrzjOcoDzXtxGaGmNhp0agAQUJWbu9pyBbOAgCBL49AKTRg@lU2JkWHkZ71W3YWPNZvgtbuvNQI7T@kzX/SSd@pl8)

NB: In order to have each typeface encoded as two characters, we can actually use any base in \$[23\dots36]\$ (because \$\log_{23}2^9\approx1.99\$, while \$\log_{22}2^9>2\$).

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 95 bytes

```javascript
c=>`2i2owi3ukgacum8
193s0cuufnghmk0
004zspr9y5072pg`.replace(/.{5}/g,n=>parseInt(n,36)>>c%26&1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY6xDoIwFEV3vqKLpg2IBQQlWhYnZ3@AprYVhdemBY0avh2ZjdO5ObnDufEH98I1tl@BuchJsUmwqk6b1DybbLhrLoZuFyRl5qkYBgX62t1pQOnm7a0rXzndplbXsZO25ULidfzJx7WOgFWWOy9P0GOIsoJUlVikxTIhkzIOt7JHgBgq8v3MA0MlnUcYEvQJEBIGvGll3BqNz71rQMfKme545e44R2IgZP9zU//kLMbpCw)

Inverse view of Arnauld

[Generator](https://tio.run/##TZFrb4IwGIW/v7@iXxbbrXsjuLglpibM3e/T3ZEEgqAsDhTYgr@elYLFD4X34Zz2nIZv78/L/DRa5YdxMgvKQpSuBQQJICIgQYBTOTYoF4wapf4EZ7VKUL3hvDE26kWLcgNc7pileqVHFXStxm023AAh2JpvdYgy39UVtjXudUGlPuhR4WOLlflpxyxbPWusAmHcXrBSJ7LRtpXEF12yWvCqQ9TJbxqV@t5esFI/tKJafWpU5i8VUCO65cAStjOAArPVMsrdaTyNXfzxVnQjhpa9sbsO@gsvHcm/ZuWU7Zl9R2zYAPwkzpJlgMtkTi3JoYjlBkyD2a8fjKP5Iqe04D4Tw2LfPKC@HTtCdEiH8S6DMEnpmiShbfIeP@J9fsxPuNHlhsEN02G7Z695SNdMPTBPJnkaxXPa6zNW/gM)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 94 bytes

```javascript
c=>`05mo1jcsjkjz8ej
zffuo1yte4zibec
vkdfk5502pbswtk`.replace(/.{5}/g,n=>parseInt(n,36)>>c-1&1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY6xDoIwFEV3vqKTaQMiqDUaLQuTsz9AKa9IwZa0FSOGb0dm43RuTu5wFB@4E7bp/VqbCmbJZsGyIqEPkyrhVKvGI6hglPJp0reH/diUIIKhrWRLabLtS/fybRFb6DsuAG/iD502daRZ1nPr4Ko91tHuQLJMrNNVSmZpLO7AI40YOtDzwgtDp2QZYUjQJ0BIGO1MB3FnanzzttF1LK155Hdu86URa0LOPzf5Ty5imr8)

Use 32-bit fact

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 43 bytes

```
⪪§⪪”{∨&×⊞ΦＶＲvRμΣ⧴ＷςCＺ¦±✳Ｚ“…⎚\`ＡW⦃$z↶c(�”⁹℅Ｓ³
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRCO4ICezRMOxxDMvJbUCylPSAwIFMNKDkRCgoIBCAykFBbBCqGoFsBCKXgUohJmgB1cAVQwxRQ@mSAHVSphNSOLIZiH0IZNQ1SheQLYKYYCSjoKlpo6Cf1FKZl5ijoZnXkFpSXAJMGTSNTQ1gRLGmprW//97/9ctywEA) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes the input letter in upper case. Explanation:

```
   ”...”        Compressed bitmap of `.`s and spaces
  ⪪     ⁹       Split into groups of length 9
 §       ℅Ｓ     Cyclically index by the ordinal of the input letter
⪪          ³    Split into 3 lines
                Implicitly print
```

The compressed string starts with the bitmap for `N` as its ordinal is `78` which is a multiple of `26`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 176 bytes

The function takes as input only uppercase letters.

```python
def g(c):
 o=bin([-233,25,65,8,81,78,9,-41,49,-311,-49,-127,87,71,73,86,83,62,-208,44,-55,-60,-39,-81,-84,-19][ord(c)-65]+422)[2:].zfill(9)
 return o[:3]+'\n'+o[3:6]+'\n'+o[6:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY9LT4UwFIT391c0cVEaTm9oC6U0ceH7/X5bWSgXlIS0pMGF/nk8Lrxxdb7MTM5kxq/pI3hlxjjPq7Yj70nD7IKEzbfeJ45LpUAWoAswYASUBirguYAcjxICGUHIEkwJJfoKjAajQEvgMjOQ58CLArjOMI9R/MENaqKqXYgrLOO6qNNcSuakrZffXT8MScUWJLbTZ/QkOKvqlL54mganrF6ztvXchUga0ntCt7Z3dvf2Dw6Pjk9Oz84vLq@ub27v7h8en54prhlj7yfs@qPfkcvYjsNr0yZUUKAb9J@QoUAoW8fZ/AM)

---

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 231 bytes (letters and numbers)

The function handles both uppercase letters and numbers.

```python
def g(c):
 o=bin([85,-3,-7,69,-33,-196,-91,47,-155,95,-221,37,77,20,93,90,21,-29,61,-299,-37,-115,99,83,85,98,95,74,-196,56,-43,-48,-27,-69,-72,-7][ord(c)-(48 if c<'A'else 55)]+410)[2:].zfill(9)
 return o[:3]+'\n'+o[3:6]+'\n'+o[6:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZBJT4RAEIXv8ys68dAQigm90d1ED@O@7ztyUAaUhNCkxYP@eSw0TjxU6uXlq1eV6j@HN9cJ0/txXFY1eQ3KMJsRt/HSdEFuFMQCYg2pRYGK2RRiy0Bq1EqBRYBzBkKD1sATsAJsAujE3EL606bRCWeIWzACMNWaaVTL30SFoRLTpUEe0Wmb5lhF7vwSL4oDaUhTk3KdLmjVvldEqbCIJEvCnGfF/Ktu2jaw4Yz4avjwHXF5JoqIPnU0crnI0pVOs2KsnSclaTpCE8aFVKk2drG5tb2zu7d/cHh0fHJ6dn5xeXV9c3t3//BI8R29b7oB7/hT05fmvurb57IKKKNA1@g/I0GD0HCFh@M3)

---

Commented code (letters and numbers)

```python
def g(input_char):
    
    # each character pixmap is encoded using '1' for filled and '0' for gaps, excluding newlines
    # resulting in a binary string ('0' -> '111101111')
    # the binary string is converted into a decimal value
    # the decimal value is offset by 410 to reduce the length of the pixmap list
    
    # pixmap of characters '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    pixmap = [85,-3,-7,69,-33,-196,-91,47,-155,95,-221,37,77,20,93,90,21,-29,61,-299,-37,-115,99,83,85,98,95,74,-196,56,-43,-48,-27,-69,-72,-7]
    
    # select the pixmap corresponding to the character
    # using the ascii value
    char_pixmap = pixmap[ord(input_char) - (48 if input_char < 'A' else 55)]
    
    # account for the offset
    char_pixmap += 410
    
    # build the binary string representing the pixmap for the characters
    # '1' for filled, '0' for gaps
    output = bin(char_pixmap)[2:].zfill(9)
    
    # insert newlines
    return output[:3] + '\n' + output[3:6] + '\n' + output[6:]
```